# Joint vs. marginal prediction intervals for path forecasts (with k-family wise error rate)

Tags: forecasting, bootstrap, prediction-interval

I am trying to become comfortable with the bootstrapping of joint prediction regions described in this paper:

http://www.nccr-finrisk.uzh.ch/media/pdf/wp/WP748_A3.pdf

This calculates the prediction intervals, $I_j$ for all time points $j$, such that all datapoints of a forecast path lie within this region with probability $1-\alpha$, i.e.:

$P(y_j \in I_j \forall j) = 1-\alpha$

The authors of the paper extent the idea to the "k-family wise error rate" which narrows the intervals by requiring that at least k datapoints of the forecast path lie outside the region:

$P(\sum_1^N1[y_j \notin I_j] >= k) = 1-\alpha$

where $1[.]$ is the indicator function giving 1 when the condition matches and 0 when it is false. N is the number of forecast data points.

By playing around, I discovered that for $k=N/2$ the k-family error rate joint prediction intervals seem to be identical to the marginal prediction intervals, i.e.:

The following seem to give identical $I_j$

$P(\sum_1^N1[y_j \notin I_j] >= N/2) = 1-\alpha$

$P(y_j \in I_j) = 1-\alpha$

Is this pure coincidence? How can this be shown formally?